# atomic operations take longer than locking (without contention)

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, atomic, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to measure the overhead of the various synchronization options when there is no contention. I use the following program:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

void function() {
    static volatile uint64_t counter = 0;
    counter++;
}

void function2() {
    std::atomic<uint64_t> counter2 = 0;
    counter2++;
}

int main() {
    // warm up the cache
    std::mutex lock;
    for( int i=0; i<1'000'000; ++i ) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock);
        function();
        function2();
    }

    std::cout<<"Starting test\n";
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( int i=0; i<1'000'000; ++i ) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(lock);
        function();
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"  With lock took "<<std::chrono::ceil<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<"ns\n";

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( int i=0; i<1'000'000; ++i ) {
        function();
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"    No lock took "<<std::chrono::ceil<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<"ns\n";

    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for( int i=0; i<1'000'000; ++i ) {
        function2();
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"Atomic lock took "<<std::chrono::ceil<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<"ns\n";
}
```

Compiling with either gcc or clang, I get similar results:

```
$ clang++-7 -g -O3 -std=c++2a locking.cpp -o locking && ./locking 
Starting test
  With lock took 2099204ns
    No lock took 2126724ns
Atomic lock took 12922543ns
```

So with or without locking the results are fairly similar (usually without locking is *slightly* faster), but with atomic operations I get a x6 performance hit.

Logic says that without contention, the relevant variables would all be local to the running CPU's cache, and all synch options would result in, more or less, the same performance.

What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder... does `std::atomic<uint64_t>::is_lock_free` return true?

Comment: I'm having _really_ strange problems compiling that test. I did check the assembly. It uses `lock add`, so whatever `is_lock_free` might return, it is lock free in practice.

Comment: I'd try to run the tests with multiple threads :)

Comment: @MFnx you can, but the whole point here was to measure the _uncontested_ performance.

Comment: Your functions do very different things.  One repeatedly increments the same `uint64_t` while the other creates a new `std::atomic<uint64_t>` every iteration.  Changing it to compare [apples-to-apples](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdbc73dc0877f68a), atomic wins out by quite a bit.

Comment: @MilesBudnek thank you, that was, indeed, a bug. The other was compiling without `-pthread`, which causes the lock to become noop. If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh Huh, I can't really take credit for the `-pthread` issue.  That just happens to be the default compile command on Coliru.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are with the benchmark program.

The first is that `std::atomic` was not declared `static`, causing a new one to be used at each iteration. The second problem is that the program was not compiled with `-pthread`, causing the locking code to become a no-op (which explains why the code with locking runs at the same speed as the one without).

Fixing both those problems yields:

```
Starting test
  With lock took 21013047ns
    No lock took 2125868ns
Atomic lock took 6744567ns
```

So the atomic approach is about 3 times slower than no locking, and actual locking is about 10 times slower.

Comment: I suppose that atomic operations are not optimized in the single thread case because you can still use them in signal handlers. If there was a non signal handlers options, they could be optimized. Anyway a local "register" like atomic object can be optimized away!